# Is there a name for this type of page navigation?

Tags: user-interface, navigation, pagination, paging

Just out of curiosity, is there a name for the kind of navigation I've been working on?

It looks like this:

`<<first <previous 1 2 3 4 5 [...] 20 next> last>>`

i.e. navigation where you've got *x* pages, but you don't want to show *x* links, you want to limit the amount of space taken up, so you show *y* links at a time, and indicate the existence of the other pages with an elision.

At some point in the middle, it would look like this:

`<<first <previous [...] 8 9 10 11 12 [...] 20 next> last>>`

with elisions on both sides.

Comment: Just don't do this (like SO): 1 2 3 [...] 4 5

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answering to just clear up this question. I hereby declare that it has no official name.

I also hereby make up the name 'elided pagination' for it.

Answer (score 2):

It's called web pagination, search result pagination.

Answer (score 0):

thresholded navigation pager?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the ordinary version of this pagination scheme is called (if anything).

However, I came up with an advanced version of it capable of handling very large numbers of pages (where ellipses (...) skip successively larger blocks of pages as you get further away from either the current page or the endpoints).

I called my scheme "Logarithmic pagination" or "Logarithmic page navigation".

You can find it (with implementation) on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835752/how-to-do-page-navigation-for-many-many-pages-logarithmic-page-navigation/).