# how to fix pagination continuous number of page IN PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, pagination

Here is my index.php code
My problem is my pagination has a continuous number of 
pages.

```
<?php
    $limit = 10;
    $offset = (isset($_GET["page"]) ? $_GET["page"] - 1 : 0) * $limit;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM employee ORDER BY employee_datecommenced ASC LIMIT                    
    $offset,$limit ";
    $list = getdata_inner_join($query);
?>

<?php
    $total = $dbcon->query("SELECT count(*) FROM employee") or
    die(mysqli_error());     
    $fetch = $total->fetch_assoc();
    for($x = 0; $x < $fetch["count(*)"] / $limit ; $x ++){
        $page = $x + 1;
        if((isset($_GET["page"]) ? $_GET["page"] : 1) == $page)
        $page = "<b>".$page."</b>";  
        echo '<a href="?page='.($x + 1).'"style="padding:2px;">'.$page.'</a>&nbsp;';
    }
?>
```

[Click here to see the output photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzHOr.jpg)

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8361808/limit-pagination-page-number

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limit pagination page number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8361808/limit-pagination-page-number)

Answer (score 0):

You say "My problem is my pagination has a continuous number of pages", but why is that a problem? What do you need to change?

Comment: i need to limit the number like this
 
`Prev 1 2 3 4 5 6 .. 40 41 Next`

Comment: why are u asking questions on answers?

Comment: 'cause the system don't let me to post a comment :(

Answer (score 0):

in your for loop while printing the anchor tags, check the current page, if suppose the page is ($current), disable ($current-1), and print $current to ($current+5) and '....' and (current+1), if current is $min or $max manage the prev and next