# Pagination dupliacates pages on first and last page

Tags: php, pagination, duplicates

If I'm on page 2 (?p=2) This is how the pager look like
`Första « 1 2 3 » Sista`
However if I'm on page 1 or 3 it looks like this

(?p=1) `1 2 3 3 » Sista`

(?p=3) `Första « 1 1 2 3`

What am I doing wrong?
I'm using the logic from another question that was posted on this site but noone seems to experience this problem as I do. [Limit pagination page number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8361808/limit-pagination-page-number)

```
function get_paging_info($tot_rows,$pp,$curr_page)
{

    $pages = ceil($tot_rows / $pp); // calc pages

    $data              = array();                  // start out array
    $data['si']        = ($curr_page * $pp) - $pp; // what row to start at
    $data['pages']     = $pages;                   // add the pages
    $data['curr_page'] = $curr_page;               // Whats the current page

    return $data; //return the paging data

}

function pagin($db,$sql,$limit,$curr_page,$max_pages=7)
{

    $res   = $db->query($sql);
    $count = $res->num_rows;

    $paging_info = get_paging_info($count,$limit,$curr_page);

    $out[] = "
        <nav aria-label='Page navigation'>
            <ul class='pagination'>";

    if($paging_info['curr_page'] > 1)
    {

        $out[] = "
            <li><a href='?p=1' title='Sida 1'>Första</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href='?p=". ($paging_info['curr_page'] - 1) ."' aria-label='Föregående'>
                    <span aria-hidden='true'>&laquo;</span>
                </a>
            </li>";

    }

    $max = $max_pages;
    if($paging_info['curr_page'] < $max)
    {

        $sp = 1;

    }
    elseif($paging_info['curr_page'] >= ($paging_info['pages'] - floor($max / 2)) )
    {

        $sp = $paging_info['pages'] - $max + 1;

    }
    elseif($paging_info['curr_page'] >= $max)
    {

        $sp = $paging_info['curr_page']  - floor($max/2);

    }

    if($paging_info['curr_page'] >= $max)
    {

        $out[] = "<li><a href='?p=1' title='Sida 1'>1</a></li>";

    }

    for($i = $sp; $i <= ($sp + $max -1);$i++)
    {

        if($i > $paging_info['pages']) continue;

        if($paging_info['curr_page'] == $i)
        {

            $out[] = "<li class='active'><span class='strong'>". $i ."</span></li>";

        }
        else
        {

            $out[] = "<li><a href='?p=". $i ."' title='Sida ". $i ."'>". $i ."</a></li>";

        }

    }

    if($paging_info['curr_page'] < ($paging_info['pages'] - floor($max / 2)))
    {

        $out[] = "<li><a href='?p=". $paging_info['pages'] ."' title='Sida ". $paging_info['pages'] ."'>". $paging_info['pages'] ."</a></li>";

    }

    if($paging_info['curr_page'] < $paging_info['pages'])
    {

        $out[] = "
            <li>
                <a href='?p=". ($paging_info['curr_page'] + 1) ."' aria-label='Nästa' title='Page ". ($paging_info['curr_page'] + 1) ."'>
                    <span aria-hidden='true'>&raquo;</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li><a href='?p=". $paging_info['pages'] ."' title='Sida ". $paging_info['pages'] ."'>Sista</a></li>";

    }

    $out[] = "</ul></nav>";
    return implode('',$out);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is due to this two conditions before and after your `for` loop :

**First:**

```
if($paging_info['curr_page'] >= $max)
{
  $out[] = "<li><a href='?p=1' title='Sida 1'>1</a></li>";
}
```

**Second:**

```
if($paging_info['curr_page'] < ($paging_info['pages'] - floor($max / 2)))
{
  $out[] = "<li><a href='?p=". $paging_info['pages'] ."' title='Sida ". $paging_info['pages'] ."'>". $paging_info['pages'] ."</a></li>";
}
```

You don't need this conditions because the corresponding pages are already displayed with the `for` loop.

Comment: Thank you! Works as intended now

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I have removed some extra codes from your function. replace your `pagin` function with following code and try

```
function pagin($db,$sql,$limit,$curr_page,$max_pages=7)
{

    $res   = $db->query($sql);
    $count = $res->num_rows;

    $paging_info = get_paging_info($count,$limit,$curr_page);

    $out[] = "
        <nav aria-label='Page navigation'>
            <ul class='pagination'>";

    if($paging_info['curr_page'] > 1)
    {

        $out[] = "
            <li><a href='?p=1' title='Sida 1'>Första</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href='?p=". ($paging_info['curr_page'] - 1) ."' aria-label='Föregående'>
                    <span aria-hidden='true'>&laquo;</span>
                </a>
            </li>";

    }

    $max = $max_pages;
    if($paging_info['curr_page'] < $max)
    {

        $sp = 1;

    }
    elseif($paging_info['curr_page'] >= ($paging_info['pages'] - floor($max / 2)) )
    {

        $sp = $paging_info['pages'] - $max + 1;

    }
    elseif($paging_info['curr_page'] >= $max)
    {

        $sp = $paging_info['curr_page']  - floor($max/2);

    } 

    for($i = $sp; $i <= ($sp + $max -1);$i++)
    {

        if($i > $paging_info['pages']) continue;

        if($paging_info['curr_page'] == $i)
        {

            $out[] = "<li class='active'><span class='strong'>". $i ."</span></li>";

        }
        else
        {

            $out[] = "<li><a href='?p=". $i ."' title='Sida ". $i ."'>". $i ."</a></li>";

        }

    }

    if($paging_info['curr_page'] < $paging_info['pages'])
    {

        $out[] = "
            <li>
                <a href='?p=". ($paging_info['curr_page'] + 1) ."' aria-label='Nästa' title='Page ". ($paging_info['curr_page'] + 1) ."'>
                    <span aria-hidden='true'>&raquo;</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li><a href='?p=". $paging_info['pages'] ."' title='Sida ". $paging_info['pages'] ."'>Sista</a></li>";

    }

    $out[] = "</ul></nav>";
    return implode('',$out);

}
```