# jQuery pagination with toggle posts = problems

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, pagination, toggle

The lack of responses I am getting leads me to believe this is impossible...

So two simple concepts:

1) Clicking a button assigned to a post will toggle the ENTIRE post (title+content), making it disappear.

2) My pagination takes all divs with class="z" and paginates them (displays 10 divs per page).

My problem is that if I'm on Page 1 and toggle (EX: toggle 3 posts) posts, the page does not maintain a constant of 10 posts per page. Instead, it will leave 7 posts on Page 1.

What i want to have happen is that for x amount of posts toggled, the next x amount of posts will shift upwards (the top x amount of posts on page 2 appear at the bottom of page 1 and so on).

I know it can be done... I just don't know how!

toggle.js (looks for a div with class="toggle" that when clicked, will send some ajax and on succes, will toggle the div)

```
$(document).on("click", ".toggle", function(){
postID = $(this).attr('id').replace('toggle_', '');

// Declare variables
value = '0';

myajax();

return false;
});

function myajax(){
// Send values to database
$.ajax({
    url: 'check.php',
    //check.php receives the values sent to it and stores them in the database
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'postID=' + postID + '&value=' + value,
    success: function(result) {
         $('#post_' + postID).toggle();
                }
});
}
```

pagination.js

```
var Imtech = {};
Imtech.Pager = function() {
this.paragraphsPerPage = 3;
this.currentPage = 1;
this.pagingControlsContainer = '#pagingControls';
this.pagingContainerPath = '#contained';
this.numPages = function() {
var numPages = 0;
if (this.paragraphs != null && this.paragraphsPerPage != null) {
    numPages = Math.ceil(this.paragraphs.length / this.paragraphsPerPage);
}
return numPages;
};
this.showPage = function(page) {
this.currentPage = page;
var html = '';
this.paragraphs.slice((page-1) * this.paragraphsPerPage,
    ((page-1)*this.paragraphsPerPage) + this.paragraphsPerPage).each(function() {
    html += '<div>' + $(this).html() + '</div>';
});
$(this.pagingContainerPath).html(html);
renderControls(this.pagingControlsContainer, this.currentPage, this.numPages());
}
var renderControls = function(container, currentPage, numPages) {
var pagingControls = 'Page: <ul>';
for (var i = 1; i <= numPages; i++) {
    if (i != currentPage) {
        pagingControls += '<li><a href="#" onclick="pager.showPage(' + i + '); return false;">' + i + '</a></li>';
    } else {
        pagingControls += '<li>' + i + '</li>';
    }
}
pagingControls += '</ul>';
$(container).html(pagingControls);
}
}
```

Comment: I don't change the id anywhere. Where do you see that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do page navigation for many, many pages? Logarithmic page navigation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835752/how-to-do-page-navigation-for-many-many-pages-logarithmic-page-navigation)

Answer (score 0):

Use an algorithm based on division and modulus division, such as the following:

```
1. Read the page number requested from the user

2. Identify how many total records exist

3. Calculate the index of the last page

4. Check whether the requested that page number is valid

5. Calculate the range of records needed for the requested page

6. Create a subset of records based on the calculated range

7. Output the records along with updated hyperlinks
```