# Best Solution of Pagination for Large Data in php

Tags: php, class, navigation, pagination, solution

Sometimes you'll see things like this:

```
[ << ] [<] ... 665 666 667 668 669 670 671 672 673 ... [ > ] [ >> ]
```

or this:

```
[ << ] [<] 1 2 3 ... 667 668 669 670 671 ... 845 846 847 [ > ] [ >> ]
```

What would be nice to have a pagination display that lets the user reach any page in only a few mouseclicks, without having ridiculously many links.

This can be achieved by having page numbers distributed logarithmically, according to distance from either the endpoints or the current page. Here's an example of what I mean:

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 . 10 . 20 . 30 . 40 . 50 .. 100 .. 200 . 210 . 220 . 230 .
>   240 . 250 . 252 253 254 255 256 257 258 259 260 261 262 . 270 . 280 .
>   290 . 300 . 310 .. 400 .. 500 .. 600 .. 700 .. 800 .. 900 .. 950 . 960
>   . 970 . 980 . 990 . 995 996 997 998 999 1000

Notice how in the gaps, numbering goes from `1s, to 10s, to 100s` (etc.).

Example Pagination on this site: Here's [a link](http://lesterchan.net/wordpress/)! 
Using Plugin : [wp-pagenavi](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-pagenavi/)!

Please share me solution or class to pagination like this site .

Thanks and Best Regard!

Comment: What have you done so far? This isn't generally a free custom code what i specify freelance site, but a question and answer (and we like seeing what has been done so far to give pointers!).

Comment: @Mabongdem, it looks to me like you've copied much of this directly from MY question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835752/how-to-do-page-navigation-for-many-many-pages-logarithmic-page-navigation.  If you want code to generate logarithmic pagination, see the answer to that question.

Comment: Also, I'm not clear exactly what you're asking for.  The logarithmic-style pagination links you describe (that actually I described originally) are not generated by wp-pagenavi, nor are they found in the example link you provide.  Are you simply asking for code to do _some_ _kind_ _of_ _pagination_?  It's really not at all clear what you want!

Answer (score 1):

I think that scroll in large pagination is the best solution. You can try it [here](http://dirty.ru/) (at the bottom)

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a `<select>` dropdown and have a maximum of 3 clicks (4 if not using onchange) to get at any page number.