# PHP Nested Pagination / Paging

Tags: php, pagination, nested, paging

let's straight to the point...

for example, I have Country and City database like this :

+---------------+------------------+

|CountryName    |CityName          |

+---------------+------------------+

| US            | Washington       |

| US            | Chicago          |

| US            | Miami            |

<--- until 100 rows for US --->

| UK            | London           |

| UK            | Chelsea          |

| UK            | Tottenham        |

<--- until 100 rows for UK --->

<--- there are 200+ country name --->

and here's what I want to do with PHP :

Country Name : US

- City : Washington
- City : Chicago
- City : Miami

-------- >> LIMIT 10 City Only ------>> SEE PAGE 2 TO SEE MORE

Country Name : UK

- City : London
- City : Chelsea
- City : Tottenham

-------- >> LIMIT 10 City Only ------>> SEE PAGE 2 TO SEE MORE

-------- >> LIMIT 10 COUNTRY Only ------>> SEE PAGE 2 TO SEE MORE

can it be done with PHP? How to do multiple / nested Pagination like this? thanks.

Comment: How about tell us where the list comes from. If the source is easy to work with (from database or arrays/objects) then sure you can do this with php

Comment: I still haven't write the code yet. I'm still figuring how's the possibilities to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE CountryName = "US" LIMIT $per_page, $start
```

Where
$per_page is the ammount of entries per page, in this case, 10

$start is where it starts, normally (page number - 1 * $per_page)

Comment: In the WHERE clause, in this case CountryName = "US" so you get the results for only US, but you can change it to "UK" or whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

If your results are going to have many pages (i.e. 100+) consider displaying a 'logarithmic' page navigation bar, as described here:

[How to do page navigation for many, many pages? Logarithmic page navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7835752/999120)