# Truncate number of pages in pagination

Tags: php, pagination

This might be a quite silly question, but I can't figure anything out that might help me go further. I'm looking to shorten the number of NUMBERS in my page navigation.

Instead of being like: *1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8*

I want it be like: *1, 2...7, 8*

And when I go to **2**, number **3** should now be seen in the numbers group.

Here is my code that is in charge of the page numbers:

```
<div id="user_nav_bottom">
<?php for($i=1; $i < sizeof($pages)+1; $i++) {
    $strong = ($_GET['page'] == $i) ? ' dark bold' : '';
    echo '<span class="normal' . $strong . '"><a href="imgit_images.php?page=' . $i . '">' . $i . ', </a></span>';
} ?>
</div>
```

Comment: What's your problem, exactly? Having been a member for nearly 2 years and asking almost 50 questions, you should know how to ask a good one by now.

Comment: Yeah true, but I tend to get blocked to simple stuff kinda frequently, and no matter how hard I try to think of a solution I can't get it myself, so I ask here. I think I described my question kinda good, tell me what you don't understand?

Comment: I don't understand what issue you're having. You can't work out how to truncate the page numbers, but what _exactly_ are you stuck on?

Comment: I am unable to make a short group of numbers for my pagination menu. There are lots of results which means lots of pages. The numbers of the pages are breaking my site (adding an horizontal scroll bar in my site) and I need to fix that with shortening the numbers of pages and replacing them with those little dots OR check google, search something and go to the bottom of the page, you'll see only numbers 1-10 are displayed, but when you go to 10, you'll get 5-15. Get me now?

Comment: How does it look with 1000 pages? Not like this I hope: `1, 2...999, 1000`.

Comment: @Sven something like this maybe? http://imgit.me/i/6p7C3A1.png

Comment: this does what u want: http://www.strangerstudios.com/sandbox/pagination/diggstyle.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a modified chunk of code I wrote for paging forums.

It's output isn't exactly how you showed but should just be a matter of tweaking.

```
<?php 
    //Set up vars

    $currentPage = isset($_GET["page"])? $_GET["page"] : 1;
    $numPages = count($pages);
    $numPages = 7;//cause I don't have the real var for testing

    $howMany = 1;
?>


<?php if ($numPages > 1): ?>
    <li>Page <?php echo $currentPage?> of <?php echo $numPages?></li>
    <?php if ($currentPage > 1): ?>
        <li><a href="imgit_images.php?page=1">First</a></li>
        <li><a href="imgit_images.php?page=<?php echo $currentPage-1?>">&lt;</a></li>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ($currentPage > $howMany + 1): ?>
        <li>...</li>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php for ($pageIndex = $currentPage - $howMany; $pageIndex <= $currentPage + $howMany; $pageIndex++): ?>
        <?php if ($pageIndex >= 1 && $pageIndex <= $numPages): ?>
            <li>
                <?php if ($pageIndex == $currentPage): ?>
                    <u>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <a href="imgit_images.php?page=<?php echo $pageIndex?>"><?php echo $pageIndex?></a>

                <?php if ($pageIndex == $currentPage): ?>
                    </u>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endfor; ?>

    <?php if ($currentPage < $numPages - $howMany): ?>
        <li>...</li>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ($currentPage < $numPages): ?>
        <li><a href="imgit_images.php?page=<?php echo $currentPage+1?>">&gt;</a></li>
        <li><a href="imgit_images.php?page=-1">Last</a></li>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this out: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/10292. This solution should solve your problem. I think its a very good approach.

Answer (score 2):

This one shows two links before and two after the current requested link:

```php
<div id="user_nav_bottom">
<?php
$current = $_GET['page'];
$last = count($pages)+1;
$curr0 = $current-2;
$curr1 = $current+2;
if ($curr0<=1) {
  $curr0 = 1;
  $curr1 = $last>5? 5 : $last;
}
if ($curr1>=$last) {
  $curr0 = $last-4 < 1 ? 1 : $last-4;
  $curr1 = $last;
}
// now print all links:
echo '<a href="imgit_images.php?page=1">&#171;</a> ';
for ($i=$curr0; $i<=$curr1; $i++) {
  $style = ($i==$current)? 'font-weight:bold':'';
  echo ' <a href="imgit_images.php?page='.$i.'" style="'.$style.'">'.$i.'</a> ';
}
echo '<a href="imgit_images.php?page='.$last.'">&#187;</a> ';
?>
</div>
```

This shows links like this:  « 13 14 **15** 16 17 »
Imho it's not so difficult to add also first five and last five links by adding appropriate conditions.

[Testing script here](http://pastebin.com/BT137NHx)

Answer (score 0):

What you might want to do is use the "logarithmic" pagination technique described in my answer here:

[How to do page navigation for many, many pages? Logarithmic page navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7835752/999120)

If you set LINKS_PER_STEP to a low value like 2 or 3, it'll produce very compact output.