# pagination php pages

Tags: php, pagination

I need help getting this pagination script to be only a little bit more complex.
I need to alter the area from line 61 to 80 to allow for the complexity described in the comments in between those same lines.

Please have a look and see if you can come up with a solution thats simple and outputs into $pages_content ...

I've provided 2 pastes...

index.php:
http://codepad.org/tWNvATES

and

The database (MYSQL): http://codepad.org/cP8hGzWN

!!! -- Please, I just need to essentially replace whats between line 61 and 80 to output something like

"... 4 5 [6] 7 8 ..."

as $pages_content...

[edit]

Here's the code snippet:

```
$pages_content = '';
for($i = 1;$i <= $pages;$i++) {
    if($pages >= 1) {
        if($i == $page) {
            $pages_content .= "<b>{$i}</b>";
        }
        else {
            $pages_content .= "<a href='?page={$i}'>{$i}</a>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Relevant code snippets really are better as part of the question, not as external links.

Comment: Done :) Added the code snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

best code to apply pagination in php available for you here, see

```
<?php
/*
    Place code to connect to your DB here.
*/
include('config.php');  // include your code to connect to DB.

$tbl_name="";       //your table name
// How many adjacent pages should be shown on each side?
$adjacents = 3;

/* 
   First get total number of rows in data table. 
   If you have a WHERE clause in your query, make sure you mirror it here.
*/
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name";
$total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
$total_pages = $total_pages[num];

/* Setup vars for query. */
$targetpage = "filename.php";   //your file name  (the name of this file)
$limit = 2;                                 //how many items to show per page
$page = $_GET['page'];
if($page) 
    $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;          //first item to display on this page
else
    $start = 0;                             //if no page var is given, set start to 0

/* Get data. */
$sql = "SELECT column_name FROM $tbl_name LIMIT $start, $limit";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

/* Setup page vars for display. */
if ($page == 0) $page = 1;                  //if no page var is given, default to 1.
$prev = $page - 1;                          //previous page is page - 1
$next = $page + 1;                          //next page is page + 1
$lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);      //lastpage is = total pages / items per page, rounded up.
$lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;                      //last page minus 1

/* 
    Now we apply our rules and draw the pagination object. 
    We're actually saving the code to a variable in case we want to draw it more than once.
*/
$pagination = "";
if($lastpage > 1)
{   
    $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination\">";
    //previous button
    if ($page > 1) 
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$prev\">� previous</a>";
    else
        $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">� previous</span>";   

    //pages 
    if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))   //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
    {   
        for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
        {
            if ($counter == $page)
                $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
            else
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
        }
    }
    elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))    //enough pages to hide some
    {
        //close to beginning; only hide later pages
        if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))        
        {
            for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
            }
            $pagination.= "...";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
        }
        //in middle; hide some front and some back
        elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
        {
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
            $pagination.= "...";
            for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
            }
            $pagination.= "...";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
        }
        //close to end; only hide early pages
        else
        {
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
            $pagination.= "...";
            for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
            }
        }
    }

    //next button
    if ($page < $counter - 1) 
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$next\">next �</a>";
    else
        $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">next �</span>";
    $pagination.= "</div>\n";       
}
?>

<?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {

    // Your while loop here

    }
?>

<?=$pagination?>
```

css used for styling is here:

```
div.pagination {
padding: 3px;
margin: 3px;
}

div.pagination a {
padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
margin: 2px;
border: 1px solid #AAAADD;

text-decoration: none; /* no underline */
color: #000099;
}
div.pagination a:hover, div.pagination a:active {
border: 1px solid #000099;

color: #000;
}
div.pagination span.current {
padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
margin: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #000099;

    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #000099;
    color: #FFF;
}
div.pagination span.disabled {
    padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
    margin: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #EEE;

    color: #DDD;
}
```

hope it help, Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep this for later.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
$pages_content = '';

$minPage = max(1, $page - 2);
$maxPage = min($pages, $page + 2);
for($i = $minPage; $i <= $maxPage;$i++) {
    if($pages >= 1) {
        if($i == $page) {
            $pages_content .= "<b>{$i}</b>";
        }
        else {
            $pages_content .= "<a href='?page={$i}'>{$i}</a>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @CharlDuPlessis I'm glad it worked. Remember to accept the answer that you found most helpful for fixing your problem, so others searching this question in the future can easily find the solution you used. :) [***How does accepting an answer work?***](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

If the number of pages can be large, consider using "logarithmic" pagination:

[How to do page navigation for many, many pages? Logarithmic page navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7835752/999120)

(sample PHP code included in my answer there).

Answer (score 0):

Basic Pagination in PHP By Amol Gholap

```
public function getPagination($pid,$totalCount=500,$countPerPage=50,$pageNumberingStart=1,$url=BASE_PATH,$maxDisplayPageNumbers=10){
        $response= "<a href='".($pid > 1 ? "$url?pid=".($pid-1) : "" )."' style='text-decoration:none'><-</a>";
        $maxNum = $pid+($maxDisplayPageNumbers/2);
        $minNum = $pid-($maxDisplayPageNumbers/2)+1;//-$pid);
        $response.= $minNum > 1 ? "<a style='text-decoration:none'>---</a>":"";
        for($t=0;$t<$totalCount;$t+=$countPerPage){
            if(($maxNum >= $pageNumberingStart && $minNum <= $pageNumberingStart)
                ){
                if($pid == $pageNumberingStart)
                    $response.= " <a href='$url?pid=$pageNumberingStart'><strong>".$pageNumberingStart."</strong></a> ";
                else
                    $response.= " <a href='$url?pid=$pageNumberingStart' style='text-decoration:none'>".$pageNumberingStart."</a> ";
            }
            $pageNumberingStart++;
        }
        $response.= $maxNum < $pageNumberingStart-1 ? "<a style='text-decoration:none'>---</a>":"";
        $response.= "<a href='".($pid < $pageNumberingStart ? "" : "$url?pid=".($pid+1) )."' style='text-decoration:none'>-></a>";
        return $response;
    }

echo getPagination($pageNumber=5,$totalCount=500,$countPerPage=50,$pageNumberingStart=1,$url=BASE_PATH,$maxDisplayPageNumbers=10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the current page number

```
if (isset($_GET['pageno'])) {
    $pageno = $_GET['pageno'];
} else {
    $pageno = 1;
}
```

Formula for pagination

```
$no_of_records_per_page = 10;
$offset = ($pageno-1) * $no_of_records_per_page;
```

Get the number of total pages

```
$total_pages_sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$total_pages_sql);
$total_rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)[0];
$total_pages = ceil($total_rows / $no_of_records_per_page);
```

Constructing the SQL Query for pagination

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table LIMIT $offset, $no_of_records_per_page";
```

Reference [create Pagination with PHP and MySql](https://www.myprogrammingtutorials.com/create-pagination-with-php-and-mysql.html)